# Making a background of a UIViewController less "alpha"

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an image that I want to use as the background of my UIViewController. I can add it as a UIView. The point is that I want to add some transparency to it. I don't want the image to be as opaque as the original image, because it has some graphics on it and would be way too distracting. So I want to make it faded, sort of. I hope that makes sense.

Maybe I should subclass UIView? Can anyone show me the code to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set alpha of the uiview from the xib else you can use `[self.view setAlpha:0.5]`

Comment: And make sure the background colour of the main view is set to something desirable, because you are going to be able to see this partially through the semi-transparent image view.

Comment: where do I put [self.view setAlpha]? in the view controller or in a subclass of uiview?

Comment: means??? In the view controller you can get the instance of the desired view and then set its alpha. If the instance name is bgView you can write as `[bgView setAlpha:0.5]`